Inotifywait doesn't wait for file operation to be finished
I have Warcraft3 installed trough Lutris and copying custom maps from /Download/ is a hassle so I wrote a script to do it for me.
Problem is that inotifywait should be waiting until downloading (I'm not sure if it's technically moving, creating or writing) is finished, then handle the file over to the rest of the script but it doesn't. The second I click download a 0 byte file is created which the script picks up and copies immediately then happily announces that it was a success.
Apart from sleep, how do I make it wait for the file to be finished being written/downloading/moving? I'm hesitant with sleep because I don't know the file sizes and download speeds of upcoming files.
I did find this post about my question:
bash script inotifywait wait for file completely written before proceding
It doesn't resolve my issue because close_write does not stop it to hand the empty file over to the rest of the script to be copied like that. It either does not wait for the file to be closed for writing or downloading is not writing.
I wrote the following script:
#!/bin/bash

#This script runs at startup and watches \~/Downloads. When it finds a \*.w3x file, it checks  ./Games/battlenet/drive_c/users/user/Documents/Warcraft III/Maps/Download/ and if the file isn't there, it copies it there and then deletes the original from \~/Downloads


#Directory to be watched

DIR_TO_WATCH="$HOME/Downloads/"

#Directory to copy the files to

DEST_DIR="$HOME/Games/battlenet/drive_c/users/user/Documents/Warcraft III/Maps/Download/"

#Run inofifywait and wait for a CLOSE event which occures when a file was open for writing (e.g.: modifying, being copied, being downloaded, etc) and then the scrpit will check if the change fits this it's conditions. Whatever the outcome is, it will get pushed to the processing below with the '|' symbol

inotifywait -m "$DIR_TO_WATCH" -e close |

#Processing events. Every line of events if there are multiple

        while read path action file
        do
    
    
        #Check if there is a Warcraft 3 map
                if [[ "$file" == *.w3x ]];
                then
    
    
                #Check if the file already exists in the WC3 Download folder specified in DEST_DIR
                        if [ ! -f "$DEST_DIR/$file" ];
                        then
                                echo "NEW TRANSACTION ---$(date)---" >> wc3_mapsync.log
                                echo "$(date) | $file size before copy: $(stat -c%s "$path$file")" >> wc3_mapsync.log
                                cp "$path$file" "$DEST_DIR"
                                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
                                        then    echo "$(date) | $file COPIED SUCCESSFULLY $path$file >>> $DEST_DIR" >> wc3_mapsync.log
                                                echo "$(date) | $file size after copy: $(stat -c%s "$DEST_DIR/$file")" >> wc3_mapsync.log
                                                echo "---END TRANSACTION---" >> wc3_mapsync.log
                                                rm "$path$file"
                                        else    echo "$(date) | $file COPY FAILED with exit status code $? '|' $path$file" >> wc3_mapsync.log
                                                echo "---END TRANSACTION---" >> wc3_mapsync.log
                                        fi
                        else
                                echo "$(date) | $file ALREADY EXITSTS, copy would be duplicate."  >> wc3_mapsync.log
                                echo "---END TRANSACTION---" >> wc3_mapsync.log
                        fi
                else :
                fi
        done


close certainly does trigger when the file is closed, but a process might re-open and re-close a file several times, depending on how it's designed. (Your own code is certainly doing that: Every time you use echo ...anything... >>wc3_mapsync.log, it opens that file, writes one line, and then closes the file until the next echo opens it again; it would be better practice to only open the log file once instead of reopening it over and over -- if the program modifying your w3x files makes the same mistake, there you are).

Anyhow -- the details of a solution call for understanding the details of the program whose behavior you're tracking / acting on. You probably should switch from close to close_write (so your code doesn't trigger on reads), and you should probably also inspect the filenames -- better-designed programs doing software downloads will do the download under a temporary name and rename to a final name when the download is done, so you can watch for the rename instead of the write, and distinguish by inspecting names.

Following the comment i received i fixed it, here's how:
I took Charles Duffy's advice and modified it. You were right that the download takes place in parts which was confirmed by the output of the script. I threw my comments out, trimmed the code and placed a sleep to the correct location where i think it reads the file names after they are closed for writing, waits (so if writing happens in parts such as downloading it can continue, resetting the cycle), then executes the second part:
#!/bin/bash

#Directory to be watched
DIR_TO_WATCH="$HOME/Downloads/"

#Directory to copy the files to
DEST_DIR="$HOME/Games/battlenet/drive_c/users/hori/Documents/Warcraft III/Maps/Download/"


inotifywait -m "$DIR_TO_WATCH" -e close_write  |

        while read path action file
        do
            sleep 2

                if [[ "$file" == *.w3x ]];
                then

                        if [ ! -f "$DEST_DIR/$file" ];
                        then
                                cp "$path$file" "$DEST_DIR"
                        fi
                fi
        done

